# Compare three columns and create a new one in R data frame

Tags: r, function, dataframe, warnings

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
ID  A       B       C
1   150529  148914  60277
2   328122  330293  531977
3   74310   78129   34038
4   97520   104695  55268
```

I'm trying to evaluate each row and identify the highest number and create a new column in this data set with the answer so I can proceed to aggregate later based on that.

I've created a function that looks like this:

```
winner <-function(a, b, c){
  if (a>b & a>c) 
    {return("blue")} 
  else if(b>a & b>c) 
    {return("red")}
  else 
    {return("yellow")}  
}
```

The function works if I run it in the command line but if use it in the form of:

```
res <- transform(res, newcol=winner(PAN,PRI,PRD))
```

I get an error like the one below and the newcol gets the value "blue" for all rows:

```
Warning message:
In if (a > b & a > c) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: Thanks Khashaa, I needed for explanation.

Comment: If your function is not a simplified version of your actual one, it seems like you could use `c("blue", "red", "yellow")[max.col(res[-1])]`

Comment: @alexis_laz This is by far the best solution and I think you should make an answer of that. I was going to propose the same exact line without noticing your comment.

Comment: @alexis_laz this solution actually does the trick! Thanks I will publish.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to all, @alexis_laz gave the exact solution to my problem.

I have changed my code to:

```
res <- transform(res, newcol=c("blue", "red", "yellow")[max.col(res[-1])])
```

and it worked as expected giving the right results. 
Thanks again to all!

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
transform(res, newcol=apply(res[-1],1,max))
#  ID      A      B      C newcol
#1  1 150529 148914  60277 150529
#2  2 328122 330293 531977 531977
#3  3  74310  78129  34038  78129
#4  4  97520 104695  55268 104695
```

This solution is also faster than `apply`:

```
transform(res, newcol=do.call(pmax, res[-1]))
```

Comment: Thanks Colonel this totally did the trick, adds an extra step but gets me out of the weeds.